# How to solve OpenCV Error "function not implemented (called functionality is disabled for current build or platform) when using VideoWriter_GPU?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opencv, gpu

## Question Intro

I'm running an opencv project in Visual Studios 2010 and have implemented cuda support (refer to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16037768/2257078) for precise info on my set-up). All cuda-functionalities are working fine - to the best of my knowledge - and are indeed improving speed on the image processing.

However, I now also wanted to attemp to speed up the video-writing function in this project by replacing the current cv::VideoWriter with the gpu::VideoWriter_GPU function. The reason for this is that the cv::VideoWriter seems to somehow cause processes running *outside of the scope in which the VideoWriter is called* to be slowed down, resulting in images available at the DirectShow driver being dropped by the VideoCapture-function, hence messing up an algorithm I've implemented.

## Problem

To attempt to solve this issue, I've now replaced the VideoWriter-calls with VideoWriter_GPU-functionality (and corresponding syntax), but when I run my project (Compile & Run in Debug-mode), I get the following error-message (directly originating atthe calling of gpu::VideoWriter_GPU):

```
OpenCv Error: The function/feature is not implemented (The called functionality 
is disabled for current build or platform) in unknown function, file 
c:slave\builds\wininstallermegapack\opencv\modules\gpu\src\precomp.hpp, line 131.
```

and the program then ends with

```
   code -529697949 (0xe06d7363)
```

I've purposely currently not included any of my code because the error-message originates so clearly from the call to the gpu::VideoWriter_GPU, which is making me think it's not a coding or syntax problem. (Please comment if you feel my code is necessary for answering this question.

## My steps so far

I miss the natural gift of understanding what precisely this message means or how to interpret it. Does my opencv v2.4.4 simply not support what I want...? Does this function simply not work on my windows 7, 64bit system...?

I've checked out as many available google-hits I could find (relating to this error message and combinations of searchterms like "opencv, gpu, VideoWriter_GPU, disabled for current build") but have not understood what the problem is or how to solve it.

Corresponding header-file and error message can also be found [here](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/OpenCV-2.4.4a.tar.gz:a/opencv-2.4.4/modules/gpu/src/precomp.hpp).

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175794/opencv-surf-function-is-not-implemented) and [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13246094/opencv-2-4-3-javacv-0-3-facerecognizer-class-lbph-update-function-still) suggest the error message is trying to tell me that opencv simply does not provide the option of using the function or functionality I am aiming to use. Or maybe even that cuda is not at all supported.. But that's all against my experience as every single opencv gpu-function I've tried to use has seemed to work fine.

## Question

Could someone please explain to me why this is not working for me, and more importantly share with me what I should do to make the VideoWriter_GPU work?

---

Many thanks!

Comment: Should you ask this of the OpenCV developers or whomever built the binary distribution you are using?

Comment: I am sorry @talonmies, but I do not understand your comment ... Are you trying to tell me I shouldn't be asking this question here?

Comment: Perhaps it has something to do with 64 bits indeed. When building openCV with Cmake do you see if CUDA is switched on?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this link can give you a little idea of what the problem is: [VideoReader_GPU not available, but built with NVCUVID?](http://answers.opencv.org/question/29976/videoreader_gpu-not-available-but-built-with-nvcuvid/).
It seems to be that the problem is the CUDA_DISABLER var.